# How to build a temporary FeatureClass in ArcObject?

Tags: arcgis, arcobjects

I want to build a temporary `FeatureClass` which contains temporary `Features` , such as points, which are useless later in programming.

While, I searched for `ArcObject API reference`, but I can't find an efficient way to solve this problem. So how can I build **temporary "container"** to store some temporary Features ?

Should I first use `CreateFeatureClass` to build a real FeatureClass and later delete it? I don't think this method is cool for I have to deal with some `CLSID` thing.

PS:This "container" must have the ability to return a `Cursor`.

Comment: Creating a feature-class and delete it afterwards is exactly the way to go. Of course you need some workspace this feature-class is created in. There are plenty of different workspace-factories for every kind of datasource, personal gdb, shapefile, remote workspace, raster... The `CLSID` by the way is not mandatory, you can leave it of as it simply references the class-extension related to your feature-class. However I suppose you won´t need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to use InMemoryWorkspace.

IWorkspaceFactory2 objWorkspaceFactory = new InMemoryWorkspaceFactoryClass();
            IWorkspaceName objWorkspaceName = objWorkspaceFactory.Create(string.Empty, p_strName, null, 0);
            IName objName = (IName)objWorkspaceName;
            IWorkspace objWorkspace = (IWorkspace)objName.Open();

Now using this workspace you can to create Temprorary Feature Classes (perform search, get cursor and than delete the feature class).
I believe that in your case InMemory Workspace is more efficient than working with ShapeFile or Personal Geodatabase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IScratchWorkspaceFactory2` interface, which is used to create temporary personal geodatabases in the temp directory.  You can find this directory by looking at the %TEMP% environment variable.  The scratch personal geodatabase will have the name mx.mdb where  is the lowest positive number that uniquely identifies the geodatabase.

```
IScratchWorkspaceFactory2 factory = new ScratchWorkspaceFactoryClass();
var selectionContainer = factory.DefaultScratchWorkspace;
```